# SQL - Find differences in tables and insert/update into table missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Express database with a table generated from a system which I don't want to manipulate so I made another table.

Table_1

```
AreaName
Area_1       
Area_2
Area_3
Area_4
```

Table_2

```
Area_1
Area_2
```

1. I want to search for differences between tables (I already sorted that)
2. Values in Table_2 missing compared with Table_1 should be inserted as new rows.

Is that possible to do in one statement?

```
SELECT 
    MIN (TableName) AS TableName,
    Area 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        'Table A' AS TableName, 
        Table_2.Area
     FROM Table_2 

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
        'Table B' AS TableName, 
        Area
     FROM [Table_1]) tmp 
GROUP BY 
   Area
HAVING 
   COUNT(*) = 1 
ORDER BY 
   Area;
```

This is the SQL I'm using now to sort ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward approach to do this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (AreaName)
SELECT AreaName FROM Table_1
WHERE AreaName NOT IN (SELECT AreaName FROM Table_2)
```

Comment: thanks, that sorted my problem. Sometimes you cant see the forest beacause of all trees ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into table1 (columns)
select Columns from table2 a
where not exists(select * from table3 b where a.ID =b.ID)
```